# Use drawable multiple times but with different colours

Tags: java, android, xml, layer-list

I have a selector for a toggle button checked and unchecked - is there a way that I can use a custom layer list with a shape and use different colours? I am adding them in at runtime but using XML as the design.

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@drawable/toggle_custom"/>
<item android:state_checked="false" android:drawable="@drawable/toggle_custom_off"/>
</selector>
```

And my toggle_custom and toggle_custom_off

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:id="@+id/mainColourOn">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle" />
</item>
<item android:bottom="10dp">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="#E6FFFFFF"/>
    </shape>
</item>
```

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:id="@+id/mainColourOff">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle"/>
</item>
<item android:bottom="10dp">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="#FFF"/>
    </shape>
</item>
```

```
        LayerDrawable layerOn = (LayerDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.toggle_custom, getTheme());

        LayerDrawable layerOff = (LayerDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.toggle_custom_off, getTheme());

        GradientDrawable toggleOn = (GradientDrawable) layerOn.findDrawableByLayerId(R.id.mainColourOn);
        GradientDrawable toggleOff = (GradientDrawable) layerOff.findDrawableByLayerId(R.id.mainColourOff);

        int colour = persons.get(i).getColour();

        toggleOn.mutate();
        toggleOff.mutate();
        toggleOn.setColor(colour);
        toggleOff.setColor(colour);
```

So for example have one toggle that is using the colour red and another using blue using the same XML. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reuse the xml for the layer-list `Drawable` and create the `StateListDrawable` for each `ToggleButton` programmatically like this:

```
void setToggleButtonColor(ToggleButton tButton, int colour)
{
    LayerDrawable layerOn = (LayerDrawable) ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.toggle_custom);
    layerOn.mutate();
    LayerDrawable layerOff = (LayerDrawable) ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.toggle_custom_off);
    layerOff.mutate();
    Drawable toggleOn = layerOn.findDrawableByLayerId(R.id.mainColourOn);
    Drawable toggleOff = layerOff.findDrawableByLayerId(R.id.mainColourOff);

    toggleOn.setColorFilter(colour, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
    toggleOff.setColorFilter(colour, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);

    StateListDrawable tbBackground = new StateListDrawable();

    tbBackground.addState(new int[]{android.R.attr.state_checked}, layerOn );
    tbBackground.addState(StateSet.WILD_CARD, layerOff);

    tButton.setBackgroundDrawable(tbBackground);

}
```

Let's test it with two ToggleButtons:

```
ToggleButton toggleButton1 = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.togglebutton1);
toggleButton1.setChecked(true);

ToggleButton toggleButton2 = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.togglebutton2);
toggleButton2.setChecked(true);

setToggleButtonColor(toggleButton1, ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.blue));
setToggleButtonColor(toggleButton2, ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.magenta));
```

[image]

Comment: It works! Thank you, much appreciated! Just had to change the `Mode.MULTIPLY` to `Mode.SRC` as I wasn't using preset colours but int values instead.