# Change shape solid color from custom drawable programmatically runtime?

Tags: android, colors, android-drawable, shapes

I want to change my custom drawable shape solid color runtime programmtically so how can i change that solid color see below what drawable i have created.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/gradientDrawble"
        >
        <selector>
            <item
                android:state_selected="true"
                >
                <shape
                    android:shape="oval">
                    <solid
                        android:color="@color/colorCrownCandy"/>
                </shape>
            </item>

            <item >
                <shape
                    android:shape="oval">
                    <padding
                        android:bottom="10dp"
                        android:left="10dp"
                        android:right="10dp"
                        android:top="10dp"/>
                    <solid
                        android:color="@color/colorCrownCandy"
                        />
                </shape>
            </item>
        </selector>

    </item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_homemenu"
        />
</layer-list>
```

Comment: @Abhi  Yes it is color from color.xml but i have many colors and different kind of drawables so i want to change that solid color so only 1 drawable work for all just only required change color

Comment: maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39364523/5015207) will help?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
// The "view" is the one for which you are applying the drawable as background.

GradientDrawable backgroundForShape= (GradientDrawable)view.getBackground();
backgroundForShape.setColor(COLOR.RED); 

// You can specify the color you want. The color defines in colors.xml
backgroundForShape.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.yourColor));
```